# Append a button to last row of dynamically created textboxes in a table

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
                Table tb = new Table();
                DynamicControlsHolder.Visible = true;
                DynamicControlsHolder.Controls.Add(tb);
                TableRow tr = new TableRow();
                TextBox txtcntrl = default(TextBox);
                TextBox txtcntrl1 = default(TextBox);
                Label lblcntrl = default(Label);
                TableCell tclbl = default(TableCell);
                TableCell tctxt = default(TableCell);
                TableCell tctxt1 = default(TableCell);
                txtcntrl = new TextBox();
                txtcntrl1 = new TextBox();
                lblcntrl = new Label();
                tclbl = new TableCell();
                tctxt = new TableCell();
                tctxt1 = new TableCell();

                lblcntrl.Text = "Item" + itemid;
                txtcntrl.ID = "txtDescription" + itemid;
                txtcntrl1.ID = "txtAmount" + itemid;

                txtcntrl.Text = rowdetail["itemAmount"].ToString();
                txtcntrl.Text = rowdetail["itemDescription"].ToString();
                tclbl.Controls.Add(lblcntrl);
                tctxt.Controls.Add(txtcntrl);
                tctxt1.Controls.Add(txtcntrl1);
                tr.Cells.Add(tclbl);
                tr.Cells.Add(tctxt);
                tr.Cells.Add(tctxt1);
                tb.Rows.Add(tr);
                tb.Enabled = false;
                itemid++;
```

[image: Table with the text boxes]

Above is the code  which creates 2 textboxes and a label on the server side and append adds the rows to the table .

I just need to show a button next to the 2 textboxes of the last row .How can we achieve this on the server side

Please adivce

Comment: Can you show us the loop you used?

Comment: foreach (DataRow rowdetail in customInvoiceDetail.Rows)
                {   //the above code goes here
}

Answer (score 1):

On your `button click event`, try this :

```
    void Button1_Click(Object sender,  EventArgs e){

 //To append a row :

        TableRow addedRow = new TableRow();
        tb.Rows.Add(addedRow);

 //To add one or more cells to the row:

        TableCell addedCell = new TableCell();
        addedRow .Cells.Add(addedCell);
    }
```

Comment: adding a cell is not problem..how do i find the last row of the table?

Comment: You mean the last index of table row? @user1567194

Comment: The code above does not append row to the last? I believe it does. For now,where the row is appending?

Comment: right now all it does is it creates a table and keeps adding the rows in a foreach loop

Answer (score 1):

after itemid++; add this condition

```
        if (itemid == tb.Rows.Count)
        {
            Response.Write("this is the last row");
        }
```

Comment: It is not allowing me to add a button to the table with in a cell .tried doing html button too .it errors out and says cannot add button to the controls

Answer (score 1):

instead of

```
  foreach (DataRow rowdetail in customInvoiceDetail.Rows)
```

use

```
  for (int i = 1; i <= customInvoiceDetail.Rows.count; i ++)
  {
    // var rowdetail = customInvoiceDetail.Rows[i];
```

so that u can check at the end of for loop that

```
  if(i == customInvoiceDetail.Rows.count)

 // u can add button here
```